# What does "狙いを定めて" mean here?

Tags: translation

I just found the word "狙いを定める"on weblio. I don't think I fully understand what it means.

To give context, guy 1 is pointing a gun at guy 2. Guy 2 then says this.

> そんなにしっかり狙いを定めて
>
> 何するつもり

Does the 1st line translate to "You're focusing so much on one place."?

Does 狙いを定める always relate to focus or concentrating or does it just mean "staring at something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

狙い is aim, 定める is to determine. Together it roughly means "focus aim". In this case focusing the aim of the gun at guy 2's body.

そんなにしっかり狙いを定めて

何するつもり

"What do you think you're doing pointing a gun at me?"